# Flask circular imports with multiple model files

Tags: python, flask

Say I have the following structure for a flask app:

```
├── app
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   ├── module2
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

Where the `app/__init__.py` file defines the following application:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from .module1 import module1 as module1_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(module1_blueprint)

    from .module2 import module2 as module2_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(module2_blueprint)

    return app
```

and the module level `__init__` files define their modules as `Blueprints`:

```
# module1/__init__.py
# module2/__init__.py is similar; just replace 1 with 2

from flask import Blueprint

module1 = Blueprint('module1', __name__)

from . import models
```

The trouble I'm running into is that the classes in both modules depend on one another. Take for example, `module2/models.py` which looks like this:

```
from app.module1.models import Model1

class Model2:
    pass
```

And compare with the models file in `module1`:

```
from app.module2.models import Model2

class Model1:
    pass
```

I made this decision because I wanted to better componentize my models, localizing each model definition to a specific application rather than having everything defined in one `models.py` as before.

How can I get around situations like this where there's mutual dependence between models defined in two different applications?

Comment: Sounds like a case for application dispatching. See [Larger applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/) and [Becoming Big](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/becomingbig/)